# Quotient of monotone plausibility

Tags: statistics

Suppose that g(t|θ) = h(t)k(θ) exp(w(θ)τ (t)), if w(θ) is an increasing function of θ, prove that g has a quotient of monotone plausibility and gives 3 examples.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22monotone+plausibility%22) suggests this is the only occurrence of the phrase "monotone plausibility" indexed, let alone "quotient of monotone plausibility".  As well as showing what you have tried, could you explain further what you mean?